Wix.com: Keep footer on bottom of page with insufficient content
The footer on my wix page is sometimes displayed in the center of the page since my dynamic page often lacks enough data to fill the entire page.
I tried using the freeze option on the footer but this means that the footer is always displayed at the bottom of the screen, even if the page is scrollable. I probably could do it with custom CSS, but I would prefer a solution with settings in the designer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
